# Not able to fetch data from joomla 2.5 database

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5, php

Hi I am trying to fetch data from joomla session table based on session id. I am using code as under and able to get session id but when i am trying to get username based on bellow mentioned query i am not getting any output. So please help/guide me if there is problem in query. I had also check column name(if i mistype) with data table and those are correct.

```
session_start();
$_session_id=session_id();
echo "your session id is ".$_session_id;

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

//  $query = "SELECT username". " FROM izj5n_session"." WHERE session_id = $_session_id";

/*  $query->select('username');
    $query->from('izj5n_session');
    $query->where('session_id=$_session_id');*/

$query
    ->select('username')
    ->from('izj5n_session')
    ->where('session_id=$_session_id');

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadResult();
$itemrow = $rows;

print $itemrow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers');

$db =& JFactory::getDBO();

$user =& JFactory::getUser();

echo $user->username

Answer (score 1):

just guessing...

```
$query = "
SELECT username 
  FROM Izj5n_session
 WHERE session_id = $_session_id;
";
```

Comment: the all code are working but problem is it does not display anything. I mean when i try (where userid=123) than result is displaying but when i use session_id(the column name) = $_session_id (variable where i store session id). i does not giving any output

Comment: I had also try to execute query in php myadmin sql tab. but there they are saying unknown column name and when i compare session id with value store in database the query is executed..................................................

    (this execute succesfull)
    SELECT *
    FROM `izj5n_session`
    WHERE `session_id` = 'qweqweqeqweweq';





    (this is not executing)
    SELECT *
    FROM `izj5n_session`
    WHERE `session_id` = `$_session_id`);

Comment: not completely.....first i was not able to fetch the data that i figure out from your answer. but actually problem what i faceing that i wrote in second comment.

Comment: thanks @Strawberry... because of you at least i was able to get data. and by the second answer i am getting proper output what i want